# Xcode doesn't recognize properties after assigning to id

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSMutableArray` of two different objects inside. I am trying to recognize the first object of the array and assign it properly. Here is the example code with my idea of

```
// I should declare a variable here, firstly I thought about "id someObject;" 
// and assigning to it in if statement.

id someObject;

if ([[someArray objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[firstOpponent class]]) {
    someObject = (firstOpponent*)[someArray objectAtIndex:0];
} else {
    someObject = (secondOpponent*)[someArray objectAtIndex:0];
}

[someObject method]; // this is OK
someObject.position; // property 'position' not found on object of type '__strong id'
```

With the idea of declaring "id someObject;" before if statement there is some problem with properties. I read that it isn't possible, thats why I'm asking for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement achieves nothing in respect of typing.

In Objective-C a *cast* on a reference type, such as `(firstOpponent *)`, does nothing at runtime; it simply allows the compiler to produce better error messages.

In your code you cast, which tells the compiler the type of the reference, and then you immediately assign to a variable of type `id` - which is the most general/least specific object reference type - and the compiler now knows nothing about the contents of `someObject` other than it contains a reference to some object.

So your code is equivalent to:

```
id someObject;
someObject = someArray[0];

[someObject method]; // this is OK
someObject.position; // compile time error
```

When calling a method on a reference typed as `id`, in your case `someObject`, the compiler does **no** checking and simply allows the method call. At runtime a check is done to verify the actual object references supports the method, and if not a runtime error will occur and the application will be aborted.

However the compiler will only call a property on a object whose type it knows. This is because it needs to know the type to determine what method call to translate the property access into. In general, but not always, the property access:

```
object.property // read a value
object.property = value // write a value
```

translate into the method calls:

```
[object property]
[object setProperty:value]
```

So you can access the property by doing the translation yourself and writing one of the second pair. If at runtime the reference object does not support the property then you will get an error and your application will abort.

Another option is to define a *protocol*, say `OpponentProtocol`, which declares the methods and properties all opponent classes should implement, and then have both your opponent classes implement it. You may then declare:

```
id<OpponentProtocol> someObject;
```

where the type means "any object reference as long as it implements the protocol `OpponentProtocol`". With such a type the compiler knows how to translate a property access into the appropriate method call, so you can access `OpponentProtocol` properties on `someObject`.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but still I get errors like "multiple methods named for example position". Is there more simple solution so that I can assign the local variable (in if statement) to the variable outside the scope? The problem is that one time it's firstOpponent class and other secondOpponent class. I'm still newbie in programming so my questions may sound silly :)

Comment: The "multiple methods" error is a different issue and it means what it says - essentially your two objects implement very different methods under the same name such that in a general call via an `id` typed variable the compiler cannot pick which one to call. You really need to ask a new question, giving details of your types, the call, the exact error, etc. and someone will probably be able to help you.

Comment: The second question in your comment is a larger topic, of course there are other ways to handle situations like this. As mentioned you can use protocols, where objects that different agree to support a common set of methods. You can use sub typing, where common behaviour is implemented in a super class, say `Worker`, and different behaviour is encapsulated in subclasses, e.g. `AutoWorker : Worker`. You can also use conditional code, where you test what kind of object you have and then execute different code accordingly. The approach used is a significant decision, you have some studying to do!

Comment: Actually I had the last solution, but the code is almost the same in both if statements, so I thought that it may be solved in a more simple way, thats why I asked here :-) I will stay with different code then, thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a protocol that your two classes can confirm to and use `id < MY_PROTOCOL >` instead of just `id` so the compiler knows what the class is capable of responding to.